# WX Bitmap from buffer, confusing invalid buffer size error

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, wxpython, wxwidgets

I process images as numpy ndarrays, then convert them to WX Bitmaps for display.

If I don't use `ndarray.astype` first, `wx.Bitmap.frombuffer()` gives me `Invalid data buffer size`, and I'm failing to see why.

```
wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image.astype(np.uint8))
```

works

```
wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image)
```

doesn't.

What's confusing is that the image is already an ndarray, of the same shape, in uint8.

```
npimage_to_wxbitmap - image:
  shape:  (544, 706, 3)
  dtype: uint8
  total bytes: 1152192
npimage_to_wxbitmap - image after astype:
  shape:  (544, 706, 3)
  dtype: uint8
  total bytes: 1152192

npimage_to_wxbitmap - image object type before: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
npimage_to_wxbitmap - image object type after: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I understand that .astype() makes a copy, so maybe that's relevant, but my image is already a deep copy of the source.

It comes from a child process via shared memory. A thread in the parent process spins to pick it up, takes a deep copy, combines it with some metadata as a dict, and puts this in a deque , ready for the GUI thread to pick it up and draw it.

I want to get rid of the .astype for speed. I believe this is 5ms slower than it should be because of the (possibly) unnecessary copying.

Hopefully there's something simple I've misunderstood!

Comment: Already solved?   Python obviously sees a difference in the data though it is essentialy the same and thus needs the astype.  What I'm missing is the code that creates the 'image' variable from the shared memory. That is the place where 'image' becomes different from what FromBuffer expects. Can you add that code to the question?